Can reflect-point-across-point be constructed using points, lines, intersections, and reflect-point-across-line?
The following is a fun problem I thought up while thinking about the role of the compass in ruler and compass constructions. It strictly weakens the ruler and compass system by replacing the compass with line reflection, an operation computable by ruler and compass constructions. I assumed the answer was negative after playing with it for a few days and thought somebody might have an insightful proof based on invariants.
Available to us are the following Euclidean geometry operations:

Add arbitrary points to the plane, or to previously constructed lines, in generic position.
Add infinitely extended straight lines between previously constructed points.
Add points corresponding to intersecting lines.
Add points corresponding to reflections of previously added points across previously added lines.

Start with two points $A$ and $B$ in the real Euclidean plane. Is it possible to construct, using these operations alone, the point $C$ obtained by reflecting $A$ across $B$? (Generic position in the operations above means the same sequence of steps must construct $C$ regardless of the new point chosen.)

Draw any line through $B$. Draw another line through $B$, perpendicular to the first line. Reflect $A$ in one of the lines to get $A'$, then reflect $A'$ in the other line to get $C$.

But do we get a perpendicular line using only these operations @GerryMyerson

We can get a perpendicular to any line easily. However, it isn't obvious to me at the moment whether we can get one perpendicular at a specified point of a line.

Are we allowed to add points at "specific distances" from another point? Like the distance would be a fixed numerical value. Basically are measurements allowed during the process

@Gwen No. Adding points at specified distances from a point is not one of the listed operations.

I just reviewed the page https://math.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions
See paragraph 1.
"This question needs details or clarity" is just false. The system allowed by the question is well-specified, not at the level of Hilbert's book, but at a level easily understood to everybody with familiarity with ruler and compass constructions - this group being the target audience for the question. The falsity of the close-vote claim is also evident by the fact that a user supplied a perfect answer 4 days before 3 of the close votes were cast.

Construct the line $L$ joining $A$ and $B$. Add a point $D$ not on $L$. Reflect $D$ across $L$ to a point $E$. Construct line $M$ joining $D$ and $E$ ($M$ will be perpendicular to $L$). Add a point $F$ on neither $L$ nor $M$. Reflect $F$ in $M$ to a point $G$. Draw line $N$ joining $F$ and $G$. $N$ will be parallel to $L$. Reflect $B$ in $N$ to $H$. Draw line $R$ joining $B$ and $H$. Now line $R$ is perpendicular to line $L$, and goes through $B$. The reflection of $A$ across line $R$ is the point $C$ we want.

An incredible solution! I was convinced for two days it was impossible after constructing the midpoint easily. I am also amused by the same question with the roles of reflect-across-point and reflect-across-line swapped, a question I've also assumed has a negative answer, though now I will try harder before sharing it.
